# Showing parents of parents of parents, using Playa to build a pedigree chart

Tags: playa, stash, relationships, related-entries

I am afraid that this is rocketscience for me, I do not understand the principle. I must show related entrees, and their related entrees, and their etcetera. In a grid, like a [pedigree chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedigree_chart)
Let me explain.

The site is about horses, and bloodlines.
Two channels, horses_father and horses_ mother, with horses_fieldgroup containing two Playa fields: 1)rel_hors_mother and 2)rel_hors_father. When creating a new horse entry the editor can relate to father and mother. I can show these relations in the HTML.

But I do not know how to relate (in principle) infinitive levels deep. Let say we have horse X-1 with father X and mother Y. I can easy show father and mother of X-1, but I must also show the father of X, the mother of X, the father of Y, mother of Y AND their parents as well. I do not know how many levels deep they want it, but the system should not be limited to amount of levels.

Is this possible with Playa? Or is it better to look for other solutions?

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit more complex than Playa.

These relationships sound similar to `cladograms` or `phylogenetic trees` in Biology, but in reverse. And similar to parent-child syntax trees, but in reverse.

Take a look at [phpSyntaxTree](http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/).

That is a PHP library to create images on-the-fly based on parent-child relationships of syntax. Example syntax and image output below:

`[Horse-0 [Horse-1][Horse-2 [Horse-3][Horse-4 [Horse5][Horse6]]]]`

[image: phpSyntaxTree results]

I could see you dynamically generating this string based on your parent-child relationships, and outputting an image based on a call to this library. It does assume you have some inner working of PHP and calling PHP libraries under the EE hood.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to embed template  for parents if you are retrieving more then 1 level parents. by passing entry id  inside a playa tag.
example

```
{exp:playa:parents ........}
{embed="template-group/template" child_id="{entry_id"}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```